# Как получить изображение из набора в редакторе?

Tags: android, android-studio

Работаю в Android Studio. Можно конечно поместить изображения для кнопки в res/drawable. Но я использую изображение кнопки из набора в редакторе. Как мне в коде обращаться к этим изображениям, например "R.drawable.ic_lock_power_off"? (так не срабатывает).

Нашел:
setImageResource(android.R.drawable.ic_lock_lock);

Answer (score 4, accepted):

К системным ресурсам надо обращаться через `android.R` класс системы, а не через `R` класс вашего проекта, который генерится в основном пакете вашего проложения. Т.е надо так (для данной конкретной картинки):

```
android.R.drawable.ic_lock_lock
```